# how can i use google earth API with backbone.js+jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, google-earth

How can i use google earth API with backbone.js+jquery mobile ?

I have created application using backbone.js, underscore.js and jQuery Mobile. 
For google earth API, I am using sample code listed at https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/#using_the_google_earth_api

My template rendering, and all other pages are working fine But when i load google earth API in one  tag, it's not loading and in js console i get message: "ERR_INVALID_DIV ".

Google.earth module never calls back initCallback, It's always calls failureCallback when google.earth.createInstance is invoked.

I explain some sample code of mine application as under, so based on that may be you get my code structure and it helps you to solve my issue.

my js code as under,

myjs1.js

```
var ge;
function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
}

function initCB(instance) {
  console.log(' init call back call ');
  ge = instance;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
}

function failureCB(errorCode) {
    console.log(errorCode);
}
```

Now my Backbone code as under,

myjs2.js

```
WebApp.MyPage= Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function (result) {
    this.template =_.template($('#myPage').html());
},

render:function (eventName) {
    var self = this;
    mydata = object dict of my data;
    $(self.el).html(self.template({mydata:mydata}));

    google.load("earth", "1");

    init();
    google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

}
```

Now my HTML code like as under,

```
<script type="text/template" id="myPage">
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map3d" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

myhtml.html

Is there any way to fix this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should at least provide some code to give context to your question, otherwise our clues are even less than yours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Earth API works with the [Google Earth Plugin](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index), which is available only on Windows and Mac OSX. It is not available on mobile devices, sorry!

If you're testing on your Mac or Windows system, you should be able to get it working. The error code `ERR_INVALID_DIV` sounds like it isn't finding the `map3d` div. I would put a `debugger;` statement in the code just before the `google.earth.createInstance()` call, and then look around in the DOM inspector and see if `map3d` is in the DOM. It should be coming in from your template if that part is working.

But this won't help you when you try to load your site on a mobile device, because you won't have the Earth plugin available there.

Comment: I am testing on my Windows system with installed Earth plugin, but it's not working :(

Comment: OK, it certainly should be possible to get it working on your Windows system. But is the ultimate goal to use it on a mobile site? That won't work.

Comment: When i try this in single static html page without backbone, underscore and jQM than it works fine but not in dynamic application which is created by backbone, underscore and jQM. So, for my dynamic application I have only option as Google Map, but i love Google Earth.

Comment: You can definitely get the Earth API working on your Windows system with Backbone and all that. But it won't work on your mobile device regardless! I assume from the fact that you're using jQuery Mobile that you are targeting mobile devices, isn't that right? Try loading the [Hello, Earth!](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/helloearth/index.html) example on your mobile browser.